# Display only <body> in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am designing a website and would like to have only the body from an external site displayed within an iframe on my site. Is there a way to display only content for a specific html element such as < body > using html/java/etc in an iframe?

Comment: No, this is not possible. An `<iframe>` shows an entire document, by definition, in a big fat security sandbox disabling further tampering with the loaded content.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong in my understanding of the question... but isn't the body of that external site is what rendered in a browser...so technically, inside the iframe it is the body of that external site...?!!

Comment: The question seems to be if you could for example 'root' the iframe at `div#example` instead of `html`. Which is only possible through XHR, with proper CORS if using an external source.

Comment: @Sai, likely, the OP does not want to load all the `<head>` resources, so the question makes perfect sense, though it could be phrased better.

Comment: As asked, the question is obscure. If reformulated as @philtune suggests, it might become constructive (though with the rather obvious answer “you can’t, and if you could, it would be illegal”).

Answer (score 0):

An `iframe` allows `"embedding another HTML page into the current page"` -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe, which means it will grab *everything*. You may just as well use Javascript to AJAX in the page you want, grab its `body` element and append it to some `div` on your page.

Now of course, this may open you up to security issues or your/their CSS may bleed... but if those are not concerns, no need to use `iframe` for this application.